# python keep alive response object

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

response = urlopen(url)
for line in response:
    do_some_job(line)
response.close()
```

I am getting some data from a url which is having very large size.
each of line will take very much time to read(avg 40000000 characters per line) and function 'do_some_job' is also expensive in terms of time.my problem here is that while executing 2nd iteration the response is closing and exception is raising and showing

```
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

if I handle this by try and  reopen new response object,how can i skip first line and start iterating from 2nd line.

Comment: What does this have to do with `r`?

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry , I removed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ScottHunter in your solution also we are reading the lines which read already,only thing we are doing is reading lines and skipping if it already read.

So the solution I implemented is- read limited characters at a time using readline with character limit

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
response = urlopen(url)
while True:
    line = response.readline(4096)
    if not line:
        break
    do_some_job(line)
response.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward way would be to re-open the url for each line, reading (and ignoring) the ones already processed:

```
lines_done = 0
while True:
    response = url open(url)
    lines_skipped = 0
    did_job = False
    for line in response:
        if lines_skipped == lines_done:
            do_some_job(line)
            did_job = True
            break
        lines_skipped += 1
    response.close()
    if did_job:
        lines_done += 1
    else:
        break
```